# Question about the signature of a matrix

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be real symmetric $n \times n$ matrices with the same rank such that $B$ differs from $A$ only by two sufficiently small nondiagonal entries. Can we say that $B$ has the same signature as $A$?

Comment: I have made a small edit, please see if it suits your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since $A$ and $B$ are both symmetric, their signature $(s_+, s_-)$ is the number of (strictly) positive and negative eigenvalues, with multiplicity. Eigenvalues are continuous functions of the entries of a matrix. If you force the multiplicity of the zero eigenvalue to be the same , as you do by requiring the matrices to have the same rank, then you get that any small enough perturbation cannot change the sign of the other eigenvalues. Therefore the signature of the perturbed matrix stays the same as the signature of the original matrix.